# Do I need to remove my custom user entity with symfony2 / fosuserbundle and sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

Initially I was using FOSUserbundle with symfony. I needed to create my customuser entity for extra fields.

Niw I installed Sonata Admin . It also has Sonata User bundle.

Now I want to know that do I need to remove my previously created User entity becasue of Sonata user Bundle or they can co-exist

Answer (score 1):

They can co-exist, just have a look on the documentation of Sonata Admin Bundle provided at this link: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html and this: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master